# javascript fetch: can't get POST response data from perl script

Tags: javascript, perl, fetch

I'm trying to get a response data back from a perl CGI script:

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
    fetch('/test.pl', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: this.state.msgName,
        email: this.state.msgEmail
      })
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("been here");
        console.log(response);
    })
    .then((responseData) => {
      console.log("been here 2");
      console.log(responseData);
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("been here 3");
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Failed!", error)
    });
```

and this perl script:

```
#/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use CGI;
use JSON;

my $q = new CGI;
my $json = new JSON;

if ($q->param)
{
  print $q->header();
  my $hash = $json->decode($q->param('POSTDATA'));
  print $q->header('application/json');
  my $msg = [ sprintf "data from %s received ok", $hash->{name} ];
  print $json->encode($msg);
}
```

but I'm only getting this (I'm using Chrome's Web Developer Tools) and no data:

```
 been here
 Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost/test.pl", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK"…}
 been here 2
 undefined
 been here 3 
 undefined
```

I'm sure the perl script works ok, here's the output of testing it from the command line:

```
 # curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"uvw","email":"xyz"}' http://localhost/test.pl
 Content-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1

 ["data from uvw received ok"]%
```

Anyone knows how to get the data response back to the js script? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this, I'm posting my solution here as it might be relevant for other people having a similar problem.

The problem was twofold:

1. I was printing an additional HTML header from the Perl script that make the JSON data wrong
2. I haven't used response.json() within the premise to get the JSON data

Here's the fixed code:

JavaScript code:

```
    fetch('/test.pl', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: this.state.msgName,
        email: this.state.msgEmail
      })
    })
    .then((response) => {
        response.json().then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        });

        return(response);
      }
    })
```

Perl code:

```
#/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use CGI;
use JSON;

my $q = new CGI;
my $json = new JSON;

if ($q->param)
{
  print $q->header();
  my $hash = $json->decode($q->param('POSTDATA'));
  # NEXT LINE REMOVED, IT WAS WRONG!!
  #print $q->header('application/json');
  my $msg = [ sprintf "data from %s received ok", $hash->{name} ];
  print $json->encode($msg);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not passing the data down the callback chain. You have to `return` something from the `then()` handler, if you expect it in the following `then()`.

```
function promiseOne() {
  return Promise.resolve(1)
}    

promiseOne()
  .then(one => { console.log(one) }) # 1
  .then(one => { console.log(one) }) # undefined

promiseOne()
  .then(one => { console.log(one); return one }) # 1
  .then(one => { console.log(one) })             # 1
```

Since the first `then()` handler has no `return` statement, it implicitly returns `undefined`, and that's what you see in the next handler.

If you're not doing any additional async work, you usually don't need to invoke `then()` multiple times.

Comment: Ok, if I do what you say I don't have 'undefined' any more, but I still don't get the response data from the perl script

Comment: Is the CGI script working? You do have a `Response` object, according to your own logs

Comment: Yes, I've tested via command line using curl and returns the data correctly (see what I wrote at the end of my posting)